# Convert Cursors to Set-Based

Tags: cursors, set-based

I need some help. I need to convert this code with cursors to set-based operations. I can't understand how I can make the set-based code do the same as with cursors.

DECLARE Cursor static local FOR
SELECT Cid,Abrev FROM EntityType
OPEN Cur
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @entityType, @entityTypeAbrev
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

```
SET @CurEnt = Cursor static local FOR
SELECT did FROM Entity where EntityTypeCid=@entityType
OPEN @CurEnt
FETCH NEXT FROM @CurEnt INTO @entityId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @RandNumber= FLOOR(RAND()*(28-1)+1);
    
        select @entityNumber=EntityNumber from Entity 
        where did=@entityId
        --print @entityNumber

        SET @FullName= @entityTypeAbrev + ' ' + cast(@entityNumber as nvarchar)
        SET @ShortName = @FullName 
        /* 
        * ENTITY*/
    
        UPDATE entity set fullname=@FullName, ShortName=@ShortName where did=@entityId
    
        UPDATE Agenda set EntityName= @FullName where EntityDid=@entityId
```

--Intervetions
SET @CurIntervs = Cursor static local FOR
select did, CredOperIntervType from CredOperInterv where EntityDid=@entityId
OPEN @CurIntervs
FETCH NEXT FROM @CurIntervs INTO @credOperIntervDid, @credOperIntervTypeId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

I need to have the same results that I obtain with cursors but with set-based operations

Comment: Stumbled across this through "set-based" tag. This needed a SQL tag, something to indicate the RDBMS in which this was written. Query needed to be formatted to be legible. User posted two questions like this, got zero replies. We'll probably never see them again, unfortunately.